# Cannot create new partition in unallocated space created by shrinking C: partition in windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu and need help installing Ubuntu along with Windows 10 in a dual boot setup. My HP laptop with 600GB hard drive came with windows 10 preinstalled and already has 4 partitions. I used shrink partition in windows disk management to shrink the C: partition from 531 GB to 431 GB leaving 100GB of unallocated space to install Ubuntu onto it.I cannot create a new partition on this unallocated space.

When using Ubuntu's disk Utility to create a new partition in the newly created unallocated space I get this error message: "Cannot create a new partition - There are already four primary partitions." I do not know how to proceed at this point. Please Help!

Comment: There isn't much you can do, other then delete one of the existing partitions. To help you figure out which one can be deleted, we'll need a screenshot of the disk management tool from Windows.

Comment: If Windows 10 was pre-installed Microsoft required UEFI with gpt partitioning. And gpt has a limit of 128 partitions, where the old MBR had a limit of 4 partitions. Post these: `sudo parted -l` and `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`